# HTML4 Line Spacing

Tags: html, web, html4, web-development-server

I am having trouble trying to decrease the line spacing here. Changing the line-height doesn't do anything.

```
<p><span style="color: rgb(137, 137, 137); font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;"> ★</span> iPhone Investor</p>
<p><span style="color: rgb(137, 137, 137); font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;"> ★</span> iPad Investor</p>
<p><span style="color: rgb(137, 137, 137); font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;"> ★</span> Brokers' client</p></div>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I recommend playing with the `line-height` in the **Live Demo** that I provided in my answer. You will see that the spacing does indeed change.

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease the line spacing by applying the [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) style to the [`p`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) element, rather than the [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) element.

Here's a full working example:

```css
.spacing {
  line-height: 18px;
}

.star {
  color: rgb(137, 137, 137);
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p class="spacing">
  <span class="star"> ★</span> iPhone Investor
</p>
<p class="spacing">
  <span class="star"> ★</span> iPad Investor
</p>
<p class="spacing">
  <span class="star"> ★</span> Brokers' client
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive, but I think you referring to the margin that is added to 'p' tags by default.

All `p` tags have a margin on the bottom, something like 15px; You can override that with the following...

**CSS in a file...**

```
p { margin-bottom: 5px; }
```

**or Inline**

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 5px"></p>
```